# Is this implementation of std::decay a correct one

Tags: c++, templates

Is this implementation of std::decay a correct one?

```
template<class T>
T DecayType(T);

template<class T>
struct decay {
    using type = decltype(DecayType(declval<T>()));
};
```

I ask because everything I came across uses some template branching to carefully manipulate the type while this seems to be acting just by definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forming a function call like that requires passing by value, which requires a copy/move constructor. That implementation is not general enough.

It is the gist of what `std::decay` does, though.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not correct, for the reasons Potatoswatter gave. In addition to requiring a copy/move constructor to return by value, you can't return some types by value at all:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
T DecayType(T);

template<class T>
struct decay {
    using type = decltype(DecayType(std::declval<T>()));
};

struct abstract { virtual void f() = 0; };

static_assert(std::is_same<decay<abstract&>::type, abstract>::value, "");

struct incomplete;

static_assert(std::is_same<decay<incomplete&>::type, incomplete>::value, "");

struct immortal { ~immortal() = delete; };

static_assert(std::is_same<decay<immortal&>::type, immortal>::value, "");
```

Comment: Very nice additions, thanks! I accepted the other one for "the gist of" :) I like that :)